# Why can't I unset an array item passed by reference in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
[0] Bert14:50
[1] hello
[2] Sarah14:50
[3] bye
[4] Dennis14:50
[5] hi
[6] wow
```

I want to reduce it to look like:

```
[0] Bert14:50
[1] Sarah14:50
[2] Dennis14:50
```

I've achieved that with this code:

```
//Doesn't any number exist in the array item? Then remove item
//by first setting it to NULL, and after the loop do some reindexing etc.
foreach($new_str as $item_key => &$item) {
    if (!preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $item)) {
        $item = null;       
    }
}
//Remove null by using unique array...
$new_str = array_values(array_unique($new_str));
//..and then remove first item if it's null
if ($new_str[0] === null) {unset($new_str[0]);}
```

But why does not this code do not remove items that does not contain 0-9? 
Why can't I unset a passed by reference value like this?

```
foreach($new_str as $item_key => &$item) {
    if (!preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $item)) {
       //Nothing seems to happen here. Output of $new_str is same as original 
       //array    
       unset($item); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want [`array_filter()`](https://3v4l.org/j1Ota).

Comment: aha ok. I'll look it into it! But I still would like the answer on my question because I'm curious. (even if array_filter might be a better solution)

Comment: Here's a better example: https://3v4l.org/ZSPnD

Comment: Use preg_grep instead `$new_str = preg_grep("~\d+~", $new_str);` or more precise `$new_str = preg_grep("~:\d+$~", $new_str);` See https://3v4l.org/YSkaI

Comment: Have you tried unseting the value using the index  `$item_key` and the original array.

Comment: `unset` on a reference doesn't remove the actual value, just the reference. See https://3v4l.org/2HicX

Comment: It could be `unset($new_str[$item_key]);` no need to use the reference `&$item`

Comment: I think the point is that `&$item` is a reference to the value in the array, not the value in the array (with it's own reference). Unsetting `$item` removes the iteration `$item` variable reference, not the value (and reference) in the array it points to. https://3v4l.org/be7Qo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$item` in the foreach is a reference to the value. See this page for an explanation about [Unsetting References](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php).

> When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between
>   variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable
>   content will be destroyed.

As pointed out in the comments, you can use unset indexing into the array by the key like `unset($new_str[$item_key]);` You don't need the reference `&$item`.

A shorter way to do this could be using [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) matching a single digit. You don't need the quantifier `+` after the character class as you are only detecting if a digit it present.

```
$new_str = preg_grep("~[0-9]~", $new_str);
```

Or a bit more precise for the example data, match a digit, colon and a digit:

```
$new_str = preg_grep("~[0-9]:[0-9]~", $new_str);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bert14:50
    [2] => Sarah14:50
    [3] => Dennis14:50
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/kTLWj)

If you want to reset the keys, you could use `array_values($new_str)`

Comment: Thanks s lot! Both for explanation and a far better solution with preg_grep!

Comment: $new_str = array_values(preg_grep("~[0-9]~", 
array_unique(explode("\r\n", $check_str)))); One-liner - real cool based on checking a string $check_str which contains \r\n.